How to find sequences that safisty these conditions?
$n\geq0$. Let $A_n$ be the number of sequences $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_{n-1})$ of positive integers that safisties

$a_1<a_2<a_3<...<a_{n-1}$
$1\leq a_k\leq2k$

So, Im trying to find $A_0$ and $A_1$ and the goal is to show that these both equal to $1$. But for $n=0,1$ this either does not make sense (typo in the question?) or Im missing something. Does it somehow have to do with the empty sequence? If no sequence satisfies the given conditions, will that give us the empty sequence ?

In first line you assume, that $n=0$ is possible, but sequence for $A_n$ starts from $a_1$ -  is this what you want/correct?

Yes, exactly my thought as well. There must be something not quite right with the question or is it assumed that we should start from $n=2$?

The larger goal is to show that $A_n=C_n$ ($C_n$ being the catalan numbers) for $n\leq3$, and for $n=2,3$ its straight forward.

What is the origin of your question?

Homework. I figured it out. The empty sequence satisfies the conditions simply because it doesnt contain an element that could break them. So for $n=0,1$, $A_n=1$.
